# Selenium WebDriver перегружает память

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, память

Мне нужно открывать вкладки и собирать данные и закрывать вкладки. Около 600 вкладок.

Проблема, что драйвер Chrome перегружает память с каждой новой вкладкой. Даже если закрывать с помощью `driver.close()` используемая память почти не уменьшается. `driver.quit()` прервёт сессию, поэтому не использую. Перегруз Chrome в диспетчере задач отслеживал, проблема не в собранных данных, а именно в открытии новых вкладок.

Почему используется память даже после закрытия вкладок и как с этим бороться?

P. S. Сайт и код просто для примера открывает и закрывает вкладки

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://edition.cnn.com/'

driver.get(url)
for i in range(25):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    driver.execute_script("window.open();")
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
    driver.get(url)
    driver.close()
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
```

Comment: А зачем вам 600 вкладок?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38164635/selenium-not-freeing-up-memory-even-after-calling-close-quit

Comment: @СергейКох просто кликая по элементу ссылка открывается, а первую страницу надо оставить. Но потом вкладки закрываю и возвращаюсь к главной, однако память грузится будто они открыты.

Answer (score 0):

запустите вручную chromedriver

```
> ./chromedriver Starting ChromeDriver 111.0.5563.64
> (c710e93d5b63b7095afe8c2c17df34408078439d-refs/branch-heads/5563@{#995})
> on port 9515 Only local connections are allowed.
```

и делайте коннекты к нему через remotewebdriver

```
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("127.0.0.1:9515"));
```

у меня под сотню-две выдерживал один такой драйвер, неделями.

Comment: Обычно от 300-400 открывается. Если вручную, то мне пожалуй, проще вручную перезапустить  2-3 раза  на том месте где ошибку выкинуло из-за памяти. Как-то в ОС надо задачи снимать у Chrome..
Впрочем спасибо!